# created date in report showing only date value in salesforce

Tags: reporting, custom-object, custom-report-type, reports-api

The standares field 'Created Date' showing as Date value when running report.
I have queried same field in workbench. Its was showing Date time value.
How can i display Date time value in report also.

Regards,
Anjana

Comment: Its very common requirement, did you do a [google search](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gpemAAA) before posting it as a question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom formula field that evaluates the DateTime field and parses out the Time (then you have to adjust from GMT to Local Time)

Or to simply display the entire value you could just use this:

**Datatype**:  `Formula(Text)`
**Formula**:  `TEXT(CreatedDate)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula field of `DateTime` type with `CreatedDate` as your formula